# SQLite.Net db size

Tags: xamarin, sqlite, xamarin.forms

There are a lot of articles on SO talking about how to get SQLite db size but none of them invole SQLite.Net's implementation that doesn't have the same methods they are calling in those SO articles.  Can I use the following to get the file size in Android using SQLite.Net or is there a better/faster way?  It seems to work.

```
        SQLiteConnection connection;
        ...
        // connection implemented in constructor
        ...
        public long GetDBSize()
        {
            return File.ReadAllBytes(connection.DatabasePath).LongCount();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FileInfo` to obtain the size (`Length` property) of the file:

```
var fileSize = new FileInfo(sdcardDBPath).Length;
```

Example:

```
var sdcardDBPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, "debug.db");
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(sdcardDBPath);
Log.Debug(Constants.TAG, fileInfo.Length.ToString());
```

Output:

```
[SushiHangover] 161792
```

ADB `ls -l` output:

```
adb shell ls -l /mnt/sdcard/Download/debug.db
-rw-rw---- 1 root sdcard_rw 161792 2017-07-28 17:08 /mnt/sdcard/Download/debug.db
```

Comment: Ok.  I get the same result but I'll go with your method for whatever reason.  Thx!

Comment: @Helzgate Using `FileInfo` will not actually load the file into memory like the method in your question, thus FileInfo will be faster and not affect memory ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Using SushiHangover's answer I created a demo app on Github that also shows you number of rows in table.  [Found Here](https://github.com/helzgate/sqlite-db-tester)